# I want to place an image on top of a featured content slider in a Wordpress header so it stays fixed while the slider fades in and out under it

Tags: css, image, wordpress, header, fixed

I'm pretty sure this can be done with CSS and divs, but I can't find an example anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to answer this without seeing any code or visual of what you're trying to accomplish. Could you post a link or JSFiddle?

If you don't want your image to overlap the slider or anything, simply having it higher in the HTML markup will mean it appears above the slider div.

If you want it to overlap, one solution could be to use absolute positioning, which is the preferred method of having something overlap another element. You may want to group the image and slider in a position:relative div, with the image or image div with {position:absolute; top:0}.

Again, if you post code and more details, I could help more.